# How do I debug JSP-embedded JavaScript in FireFox debugger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, debugging, firefox

I am using the FireFox debugger to debug an app that contains both `.JSP` files and `.js` include files.  The debugger lets me put break points in the `.js` files, but NOT in the JavaScript/JQuery that is in the `.JSP` files that call the `.js` files.  Debugging is not entirely useful unless I can put breakpoints in ALL the files that contain JavaScript and JQuery code, no matter what file extension is attached to each file.

**How can I get FireFox to include the relevant JSP files in the list of files to which break points can be added?**

For example, the file somejsp.jsp contains the following script element:

```
<script language="javascript">

    function someMethod(someArgument) {
    document.forms['someForm'].elements['someElement'].value = some.element;
    //some other JavaScript code  
    }

</script>

Rest of JSP file...
```

If I take @charlietfl's suggestion and add the `debugger` command, where and how do I add it?

I made a first attempt to write it as follows:

```
debugger document.forms['someForm'].elements['someElement'].value = some.element;
```

But when I try to run the code, the browser gives an error alert saying that `someMethod()` has not been implemented.  So it seems that adding the word `debugger` in the way shown above causes the method to become invisible to FireFox.  How can I correctly add the breakpoint?

Comment: Why are you putting javascript into jsp files in the first place? Have you tried to maintain separate files for each?

Comment: @andrewdleach That is not my decision.  I am asking how to work with what I have to work with.  Do you know how to do what the OP asks?

Comment: can put `debugger` command in the code you want to debug

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you very much.  But I do not know what you mean.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: that command sets breakpoint when it is encountered in the code itself

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you.  I edited the OP to include the results of my attempt at following your suggestion.  I must not understand you.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `some.element`? Can't set value to be an element...needs to be a string. Also where is `someMethod()` being called?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in Chrome browser.

You need to enable the below setting in DevTools first:

- Navigate to Settings > Preferences
- Check ***Search in anonymous and content scripts*** under **Sources** section

Now Navigate to your page as usual, right-click and open DevTools. Select **Search** tab at the lower part of the DevTools window and enter keywords specific to the text in the JavaScript code that you're trying to search.